# OAuth client secrets in React apps

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have been trying to learn about **OAuth2** and **OpenID Connect** and this article was the most helpful so far:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/21/illustrated-guide-to-oauth-and-oidc

But it made me wonder:

If the "client secret" is supposed to be a secret (duh) between the **Client** and the **Authorization Server**, and the **Resourse Owner** is never supposed to know about it... how does this work in things like React, where the **Client** is run directly in the "client-side" (redundant terminology...).

I am guessing that you are not supposed to distribute your "client secret" publicly, so you clearly cannot deliver it along with your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A React SPA is a 'public client' and does not have a client secret, since, as you indicate, it cannot. be stored securely in a browser.

For React you would use [Authorization Code Flow + PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-7) to sign users in. This involves use of a secret that is generated at runtime - as well as an end user providing credentials.

It is also possible (and recommended in 2021) to proxy OAuth requests that involve tokens via a Back End for Front End API.
This allows the API to attach a client secret and in effect this upgrades the SPA to a 'confidential client'.

**FURTHER INFO**

I think more libraries will become available that implement this type of security in 2021. See also [this video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html).

Comment: So what you are saying (in the second case) is that the client is divided in 2 parts, one on the client-side and another on the server-side? Is there any know implementation/tutorial/package that you could recommend me, to figure out how would something like that be built?